# GWT Ckeditor "i.contentWindow is null" issue

Tags: gwt, ckeditor

i am using GWT ckeditor in my application, while switching over between two or more editor instance, i get the error "***i.contentWindow is null***". i refered more solutions but nothing works for me. Is there any difference between ckeditor and GWT ckeditor? Or is there any specific thing i need to work with on GWT editor?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: i use this to delete the instance but it doesn't work 
" if(CKEDITOR.instances[editorName])
  delete CKEDITOR.instances[editorName];
  CKEDITOR.replace(editorName); "
in my ckeditor.js file

Comment: the editor instance name generates randomly and how to get its name? @ClassStacker

Comment: Instead of just `CKEDITOR`, try referring to all of these as `$wnd.CKEDITOR` - adding `$wnd` will make sure these calls are run in the right window. That's all I can suggest without seeing something that looks like real code...

Comment: @ClassStacker I need to know that how to get the name of the editor, it don't have a textarea name or something in gwt ckeditor code.